# How to chomp a string after second occurrence of a certain character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string with an address:

`3rd Street Promenade, Santa Monica, CA, United States`

How do I chomp it off non-destructively after (and including) the second comma?

This is going to get used in a view so as concise as possible is preferable.

Comment: Do you not have some object that contains the string as separate parts? I.e. an Address object?

Comment: I just save it directly from Google Maps Places Library, and because of the results' arbitrary length (variable number of components) and I only need street and city - I'm thinking of going this path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"3rd Street Promenade, Santa Monica, CA, United States"[/[^,]*,?[^,]*/]
# => "3rd Street Promenade, Santa Monica"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'3rd Street Promenade, Santa Monica, CA, United States'.clone.split(/,/).take(3).join(', ')
```

Comment: The `clone` is unnecessary. And don’t you mean `take(2)`?